# how to setup a wireless bridge for WAG120N linksys?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I have recently bought a WAG120N modem/router-linksys in order to extend the range in the house, and I have a WAG200G which is my old modem that I use it to connect to the internet.

**What I am trying to achieve** is that I want my WAG120N to be my wireless bridge and gain the internet from WAG200G

**What I have done so far:**
I went to WAG120N setup 192.168.1.1, and the picture below showed how I setup the modem. I am actually a beginner in networking. So, I changed the **encapulation to RFC 2684 Bridged** and in the IP settings, the default gateway and primary DNS is my the IP address of my old modem WAG200G.

Setup Image: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmPnj.png)

I tested but didn't work. I know I might need to change my old modem WAG200G settings but I stopped and I thought someone would advice me what to do.

Comment: There is no picture in your post. How is the WAG120N connected (at least in your plan) to the WAG200G?

Comment: Sorry. I added now in the post

Comment: My other question?

Comment: I am trying to connect WAG120N to WAG200G wirelessly, so the internet from WAG200G goes to WAG120N. I hope it is possible to do it.Thanks

Comment: No it is not. Your router, WAG120N, like all routers, only has one wireless interface, while you need two for the functionality you have in mind. You will need to buy a `wireless bridge` for that (notice,`not` a wireless Access Point, =AP).

Comment: Or a wireless repeater, or range extender. Just for the sake of completeness

Comment: Thanks Marius. Yes you right. It can't be done wirelessly unless if I bought a router that supports this functionality. What I have done so far, I have connected my WAG200G modem to my new router WAG120N by cable and it has extended.

Comment: By cable it is a different matter. I suggest you turn off DHCP on the router, if DHCP is already enabled on the WAG200G. This way you will have a single network, and you will be able to access any machine from any other machine without any problem.